# call a matlab script in a script

Tags: matlab

I have two matlab script files .m (not function files) and if I want to call another script in my current script, which command should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the answer.

Just name the script in the other script:

```
myOtherScript
```

You can use run('myOtherScript') if you prefer, but it will end up internally 
doing the same thing as naming it directly; you might, though, like the 
emphasize that it gives that it is a script being mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass parameters to it, enclose them in parentheses.

```
angle=.78; bias=.001; 
myOtherScript(angle, bias)
```

If you want to return parameters from it, do it like this:

```
adjustedAngle = myOtherScript(angle, bias);
```

Or multiple return values:

```
[status adjustedAngle] = myOtherScript(angle, bias);
```

If you don't want the return values immediately reflected to the command window (maybe this call is in a big loop and you're going to plot all the values later), be sure to put a semicolon after the call statement.

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to a script. A script is not a function!

Answer (score 2):

As you said, if your script2 is in the same folder as your script1, you can call it with its name.
`script2`

If it is in another folder, you can use 'run'.
`run("../path/to/your/script/script2")`

Answer (score -3):

In script test1.m put this:
function test1
    disp('test 1')

```
aaa=111;

test2( aaa );
```

end

In test2.m put this, then run test1.m:
function test2(aaa)
    fprintf('test 2  aaa=%d !!!\n', aaa )
end

Comment: There is a different between functions and scripts. Question asks about scripts, your answer is for functions.