# Open and run a .m in matlab into an another .m file (from another directory)

Tags: matlab, directory, command, execute, subroutine

I have a question about a code I am creating.

I have a code in a .m file, let's name it as "first.m".

But in the "first.m" i would like to write a command in this script in which I would like to run and execute an another .m file, let's name it "second.m" file, which is in a different directory.

I mean I would like to use a subroutine, but the main problem is that I do not have understand how can I use subroutines in MATLAB.

Could anyone help me to make it?

Comment: You just need to put the name of that script i.e `second` inside `first.m`. `second.m` should be in your path. Otherwise write the complete path to that m file and use `run`

Comment: Almost the same question, but doesn't specify the second script being in a different directory: [call a matlab script in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5226840/7328782).

Comment: Re: "I would like to use a subroutine [...] I do not have understand how can I use subroutines in MATLAB": You are looking to use functions. Please read [the documentation on the basics of functions in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try coding using the run function.
It is important that Matlabs knows where to find that function. You can use the function `addpath`
Also, you can actually copy the full path in that command. Like this:

```
run('C:\Users\user\Desktop\second.m')
```

Make sure you write the correct path that contains second.m. If the code is in the same path as first.m or you have already added the path you can use:

```
run('second.m')
```

And if they are in a subfolder of the actual folder where first.m is, you can use the first example or:

```
run('subfolder\second.m')
```

Comment: `run('second.m')` is the same as `second`, but more verbose.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I use `run` because i usually have functions' names in a variable, so i can write `run(variable)`

Comment: Thank you both for your help !!